# How to assign output of `Last@Reap` to a variable?

Tags: assignment, sow-reap

I would like to define a variable that equals the solution of a numerical equation. Usually something like `smax=zmax/.FindRoot[Exp[-zmax/2]==2,{zmax,0}]` would work. The value of `smax` would be numerical. In the following, `smax` gets assigned the non-numerical string `zmax` instead of the numerical solution.

How to assign the numerical solution to a variable instead of assigning the label of the solution?

```
smin = -1;
h[z_] := Exp[-z/2]
smax=zmax/.Last @ Reap[
    NDSolveValue[
        {
        int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
        WhenEvent[int[z]==0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]
        },
        int,
        {z, smin, Infinity}
    ],
    _,
    #1 -> First@#2&
]
```

It seems I need to somehow delay the assignment until after the evaluation. 
I also tried

```
sol = Last@
  Reap[NDSolveValue[{int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[int[z] == 0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]}, 
int, {z, smin, Infinity}], _, #1 -> First@#2 &]
smax = zmax /. First@sol
```

and

```
sol = Last@
  Reap[NDSolveValue[{int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[int[z] == 0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]}, 
int, {z, smin, Infinity}], _, #1 -> First@#2 &]
smax = zmax /.sol
```

and

```
smax = Hold[
  zmax /. Last@
Reap[NDSolveValue[{int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[int[z] == 0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]}, 
  int, {z, smin, Infinity}], _, #1 -> First@#2 &]
]
```

The input forms of the output are

```
{InterpolatingFunction[
  {{-1., 
    0.9999999503483246}}, 
  {5, 7, 1, {29}, {4}, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, 
   False}, {{-1., 
   -0.9999015069919955, 
   -0.9998030139839911, 
   -0.9941899410658487, 
   -0.9885768681477063, 
   -0.9829637952295639, 
   -0.9656960118691706, 
   -0.9484282285087774, 
   -0.9311604451483841, 
   -0.9138926617879909, 
   -0.8793570950672045, 
   -0.844821528346418, 
   -0.8102859616256315, 
   -0.775750394904845, 
   -0.7412148281840585, 
   -0.6364160981321162, 
   -0.5316173680801739, 
   -0.42681863802823167, 
   -0.3220199079762894, 
   -0.2172211779243471, 
   -0.11242244787240478, 
   0.09310080516319964, 
   0.25133693191093665, 
   0.38002571750014225, 
   0.5087145030893478, 
   0.6374032886785534, 
   0.7660920742677592, 
   0.8947808598569648, 
   0.9999999503483246}}, 
  {Developer`PackedArrayForm, 
   {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 
   14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 
   26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 
   38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 
   50, 52, 54, 56, 58}, {0., 
   -1.0421906109874948, 
   -0.00010263754935876063, 
   -1.0420795489780026, 
   -0.00020526416013504978, 
   -1.0419684894957806, 
   -0.006036157749020502, 
   -1.0356434260875778, 
   -0.011831571189832578, 
   -1.0293265200823063, 
   -0.017591550131026527, 
   -1.0230177217238963, 
   -0.03508953803441338, 
   -1.0036599518365754, 
   -0.05225392606613451, 
   -0.9843769993273269, 
   -0.06908597587427147, 
   -0.9651674267571602, 
   -0.08558694219637947, 
   -0.9460298021571588, 
   -0.11760052213606785, 
   -0.9079646957022863, 
   -0.1483042124375252, 
   -0.870170329566471, 
   -0.17770716293874222, 
   -0.8326354340838389, 
   -0.20581814386923664, 
   -0.7953488169584483, 
   -0.2326455374667564, 
   -0.7582993599269294, 
   -0.3062765350826772, 
   -0.6472108015918777, 
   -0.3683613617451538, 
   -0.5378996923572129, 
   -0.41907053594729565, 
   -0.43006582874627264, 
   -0.4585433186321676, 
   -0.32341306427417876, 
   -0.48688811403985527, 
   -0.21764849613430565, 
   -0.5041827660984485, 
   -0.11248166079293165, 
   -0.5061691280086447, 
   0.09313443278259884, 
   -0.47887710321230265, 
   0.2519989968825433, 
   -0.43807650845487345, 
   0.3823166468446675, 
   -0.3804094520455811, 
   0.5142177107173006, 
   -0.30563706497632676, 
   0.6482484738402796, 
   -0.21344968009960505, 
   0.7849640419787253, 
   -0.10346548870948925, 
   0.9249306403654647, 
   -3.0461744238152733*^-15, 
   1.0421905549989765}}, 
  {Automatic}], 
 {{0.9999999503483246}}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your  `Last @Reap[...]`  returns `{"zmax" -> 1.}` you should use `"zmax"` in `ReplaceAll`:

```
rule = Last@Reap[NDSolveValue[{int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[int[z] == 0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]}, 
     int, {z, smin, Infinity}], _, #1 -> First@#2 &];
smax = "zmax" /. rule
```

> 1.

Alternatively, you can use one-argument form of `Reap` and simply get `Part` (2,1,1) of `Reap[...]` output:

```
out = Reap[NDSolveValue[{int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[int[z] == 0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]}, int,
     {z, smin, Infinity}]];
smax = out[[2, 1, 1]]
```

> 1.

Comment: Both solutions still assign the label `zmax` to `smax` for me, not the numerical value `1.`. I copy-pasted your solutions, so it is interesting that the results differ.

Comment: @Sander, try starting with fresh kernel, or use `ClearAll[smax, zmax]` before you execute the relevant code. If you still have the same issue it is probably version/os issue. Both methods work without issue  in version 9 /windows10 and version 12 /wolfram cloud.

Comment: Quitting and restarting the kernel, quitting and restarting Mathematica and `ClearAll` did not change anything: the label `zmax` is still assigned, not `1.`. Using Ubuntu 18.04, Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: @Sander, interesting. Can you post the input forms of the outputs from `Last@Reap[
  NDSolveValue[{int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[int[z] == 0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]}, 
   int, {z, smin, Infinity}], _, #1 -> First@#2 &]` and from `Reap[NDSolveValue[{int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[int[z] == 0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]}, int,
     {z, smin, Infinity}]]`?

Comment: Not sure what the input forms of the outputs are (Googling didn't help), but the outputs are `{"zmax" -> 1.}` and `{InterpolatingFunction[*small picture*],{{1.}}}` where the small picture says Domain: {{-1.,1.}} Output:scalar

Comment: InputForms added as an edit to the question, because too long to copy to comment.

Comment: @Sander, one last thing: in your version/os (1) what does `"zmax" /. {"zmax" -> 1.}` give and (2) what does `{InterpolatingFunction[*small picture*],{{1.}}}[[2,1,1]]`  (I mean go to the right of output cell with `{InterpolatingFunction[*small picture*],{{1.}}}` in it and put `[[2,1,1]]` and shit-enter) give?

Comment: `"zmax" /. {"zmax" -> 1.}` gives `1.`. Changing the input to add `[[2,1,1]]` to the end gives the output `1.`. Clicking the plus sign on the small picture expands it a bit, revealing `Order:3 Method:Hermite Periodic:False` in addition to the previous `Domain:...`

Comment: kglr's answer works today. I did not change anything or even restart the computer. I have no idea why it did not work yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code uses "zmax" (with quotes) to Sow the value, but uses zmax (without quotes) for the call to ReplaceAll. Removing the quotes returns the expected numerical value. (At least it does that in Mathemematica 12.0 under Windows 10.)

BTW: Both solutions from kgrl work for me (with Mathematica 12.0)